# Strange prepared statements error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here is how my statement looks like.

```
               $stmt = $this->db->prepare("
                        select q.id 
                        from questions q 
                        left outer join (
                        select max(chk_date) as questions_last_chk_date 
                        FROM last_check_date 
                        where user_id = ? 
                        AND chk_token=?) lcd 
                        on q.add_dt > lcd.questions_last_chk_date
                        WHERE q.author_id<>?
                ") or die($this->db->error);
                $stmt->bind_param("isi", $_SESSION["userID"], "q", $_SESSION["userID"]) or die($stmt->error);
```

I got 2 questions

1) Getting error message

**Fatal error**:  Cannot pass parameter 3 by reference

why this error occurs? BTW, I know that `last_check_date` table is empty but I think it's not related with this problem.

2) On windows, getting error message table `last_check_date` doesn't exist, but I 100% know that there is no typo, and table exists. I tried the same query with Navicat - db amanger application and got result. But when I try with PHP getting this error. On remote Linux server it works, and getting error message in question 1. Tried to restart mysql service, rename to other name and change name back to previous. No success! How can I fix that problem?

Comment: I am not an MySQLi expert but I think you can not bind static parameters to a query. Which in my eyes is perfectly reasonable. So either you set parameter 3 into a variable and pass it or you change your query so that that what is now parameter 3 is already in there.

Comment: @clentfort I gachu. But can't get this work with outer join. I have no experience with outer joins. Thats why posted question to community

Answer (score 3):

You have to put `q` into a variable.

FYI, try not to use string values equals to tables alias or references. You are passing value of `q` when you have a table with the `q` alias. This is not an error, but maybe could be very confusing in case you need to do an echo of your query.